# Works but I am not sure why, objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, methods, segue

I am making a calculator and have two MVC's one for the math portion called CalculatorFirstViewController with a class called CalculatorBrain. The other one  for the graph portion called GraphViewController.

In the CalculatorController I use a mutableArray as the calculator stack and pass it to the graph view controller via segue. The GraphView's properties is called graphingPoints. After that go through drawrect and call "programToGraph" method which will create an array of points to graph. What confuses me is that I call a method "runProgram:usingVariableValues" within "programGraph" although "runProgram" is only declared in CalculatorBrain which is a seperate object file. Why does this method call work?

```
@interface CalculatorFirstViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation CalculatorFirstViewController
@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain*) brain{
   if(!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
   return _brain;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Graph"])
   //The call [self.brain program] returns the CalculatorStack
    [segue.destinationViewController setGraphingPoint:[self.brain program]];
  }
```

Here is the declaration of RunProgram, which is declared in the CalculatorBrain Object used in the Calculator MVC. It is a Class Method. All it does is return the value of doing the operations on the stack.

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary*)variableValues;
```

This is the graphViewController Code.

```
-(void) setGraphingPoint:(NSMutableArray*) graphingPoint{

if(_graphingPoint == nil) _graphingPoint = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
    _graphingPoint = graphingPoint;
    //this will call drawrect
    [self.graphingView setNeedsDisplay];
}


-(id) programToGraph:(GraphingView *)sender{

    CGPoint graphPoint;
    NSMutableArray *pointValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for( int x =0;x<5; x++)
    {
        NSDictionary* xValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"X"];
        graphPoint.x =x;

     //This is the main part I dont get, If calculatorBrain is a seperate object file 
     //and I didn't import it, how am I able to call the method by just saying 
     //CalculatorBrain as the receiver? 

        graphPoint.y = [CalculatorBrain runProgram: self.graphingPoint usingVariableValues:xValue];

        [pointValues addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:graphPoint]];

}

return pointValues;

}
```

So how come I can call runProgram although I didnt import the CalculatorBrain file and I didnt pass it via segue to the other controller?

Comment: You do realize that you have to be importing this thing either in the m or the h, because you have access to the CalculatorBrain class.  Or you have a forward reference to it (@class), but then CLANG would be complaining about it.

Comment: I didnt import any of the CalculatorFiles into the graphingController but I didnt import the CalculatorController into the CalculatorControlelr to be able to call the segue. I thought U had to keep the MVC seperate though

Comment: Did you @class anything at all?

Comment: I used @class to declare a protocol to make a delegate and then had my graphing Object use that protocol to call ProgramToGraph, I didnt use it in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c allows calls to selectors (methods) on objects without the need for the declaration. This is because the actual call is looked up at runtime. This allows your code to have extension methods for classes which are implemented in other libraries as the call is found at runtime when it is needed, rather than at compile time.

So your call is looked up at runtime and works fine, as the method exists. In this situation the compiler should give a warning that the method is not found at compile time, but will still compile successfully.

Edit: you will still need to forward declare the class itself using @class.

Comment: What about setters and getters arent those technically methods? If so then why do I need to pass information through a segue if I can still call it anywhere I want?

Comment: "Objective-c allows calls to selectors (methods) on objects without the need for the declaration" Absolutely not true.  The compiler will complain all the way to timbuktu if you tried to do anything remotely close to that without `-performSelector:`

Comment: if I import the the GraphingViewController into the CalculatorController to call the setter in the segue will this allow the graphingViewController to use the methods in the CalculatorViewController?